# Separate XML node values into separate rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

I have a SQL table with a XML column. The value of the column looks like this:

```
 <StudentGroup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <StudentIds>
    <int>3000</int>
    <int>3001</int>
    <int>3002</int>
    <int>8</int>
    <int>9</int>
  </StudentIds>
</StudentGroup>
```

I want to get the each StudentIDs in a separate row instead of it in one row. Here is what I have done:

```
select
    xmlColumn.value('(/StudentGroup/StudentIds)[1]','varchar(max)') as IDs  
from myTable
```

This select statement returns the IDs in one row. Like this:

```
30003001300289
```

What is want is

```
3000
3001
3002
8
9
```

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have the XML in a variable:

```sql
DECLARE @x XML = '
<StudentGroup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <StudentIds>
    <int>3000</int>
    <int>3001</int>
    <int>3002</int>
    <int>8</int>
    <int>9</int>
  </StudentIds>
</StudentGroup>';

SELECT
    n.v.value('.','INT') AS ID
FROM
    @x.nodes('/StudentGroup/StudentIds/int') AS n(v);
```

---

When you have the XML in a table:

```sql
DECLARE @x XML = '
<StudentGroup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <StudentIds>
    <int>3000</int>
    <int>3001</int>
    <int>3002</int>
    <int>8</int>
    <int>9</int>
  </StudentIds>
</StudentGroup>';

DECLARE @t TABLE(
    x XML
);
INSERT INTO @t(x)VALUES(@x);

SELECT
    n.v.value('.','INT') AS ID
FROM
    @t
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/StudentGroup/StudentIds/int') AS n(v);
```

Comment: Let me rewrite that for a table... Sorry fast poster ;)

Comment: Thanks!! that is exactly what i was looking for.